# R: Fill empty cell with value of last non-empty cell

Tags: r, cell, fill

In Excel, it is easy to grab a cell within a column and drag the cursor downward to replace many cells below so that each cell becomes the same value as the original.

This function can be performed in R using a for loop. I spent some time trying to figure it out today, and thought I'd share for the benefit of the next person in my shoes:

```
for (row in 2:length(data$column)){ # 2 so you don't affect column names
    if(data$column[row] == "") {    # if its empty...
        data$column[row] = data$column[row-1] # ...replace with previous row's value
    }
}
```

This worked for me, although it took a long time (5-10 mins) to run with a huge data file. Perhaps there is a more efficient way of achieving this function, and I encourage anyone to say how that could be done.

Thanks and good luck.

Comment: `library(zoo)` `na.locf()` is faster I believe.

Comment: Not a question, so does it belong as one?

Answer (score 12):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:5, "", 3, "", "", "", 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
   a
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6   
7  3
8   
9   
10  
11 4

while(length(ind <- which(df$a == "")) > 0){
  df$a[ind] <- df$a[ind -1]
}

> df
   a
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  5
7  3
8  3
9  3
10 3
11 4
```

**EDIT:** added time profile

```
set.seed(1)
N = 1e6
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c("",1,2),size=N,replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if(df$a[1] == "") {df$a[1] <- NA}

system.time(
  while(length(ind <- which(df$a == "")) > 0){
    df$a[ind] <- df$a[ind - 1]
  }, gcFirst = TRUE)

user  system elapsed 
0.89    0.00    0.88
```

Comment: Your while loop is a truly beautiful solution in the way it takes advantage of R's vectorization.

Answer (score 7):

Here  fast solution using `na.locf` from the `zoo` package applied within `data.table`. I created a new column **y** in the result to better visualize the effect of replacing missing values( easy to repalce **x** column here). Since `na.locf` replaced missing values , an extra step was needed to replace all zero length values by `NA`. The solution is very fast and takes less than *half second* in my machine for *1e6* rows.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
N=1e6  ##  number of rows 
DT <- data.table(x=sample(c("",1,2),size=N,replace=TRUE))
system.time(DT[!nzchar(x),x:=NA][,y:=na.locf(x)])
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.59    0.30    1.78 
# x y
# 1:  2 2
# 2: NA 2
# 3: NA 2
# 4:  1 1
# 5:  1 1
# ---     
#   999996:  1 1
# 999997:  2 2
# 999998:  2 2
# 999999: NA 2
# 1000000: NA 2
```

Comment: A minor issue. If there are actual `NA` values in the data, this will replace them as well. As per `dt <- data.table(x=c(1,NA,2,"",""))` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail good catch even if `NA` and `""` are in the same spirit of missing values! I wait for the user example and expected result before going further with this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing agstudy's MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

N = 1e6
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c(NA,"A","B"), size=N, replace=TRUE))

system.time(test <- df %>% dplyr::do(zoo::na.locf(.)))
```

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.082   0.000   0.130
```

Answer (score 1):

just to provide a more recent update;

tidyr::fill() is faster than lightning

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

N = 1e6
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c(NA,"A","B"), size=N, replace=TRUE))

system.time(test <- df %>% tidyr::fill(x))
```

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02
```